# Node.js HTTP Request Parse Dom Data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, svg, httprequest

I want to get data attributes inside the svg element from github.com/profile_name with node.js http request and parse it to JSON data.

```
<rect class="day" width="10" height="10" x="-36" y="10" fill="#ebedf0" data-count="0" data-date="2017-09-03"></rect>
```

Output will be:
"days":[ "day": 2017-09-03, 
         "count": "10" ]

I can get the body with Simplified HTTP Request but I can't figured it out how can parse the body and make Json file.

```
const request = require('request');

    request('http://www.github.com/acgrdumlu', function (error, response, body) {
      console.log('error:', error);
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
      console.log('body:', body); 

      }
    });
```

Comment: If the data you're getting is a regular HTML page and you want to parse that, you will need to use an HTML parser such as [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) in order to get one particular piece of the content.  Once cheerio has parsed it, then you can use cheerio's DOM search methods (which are jQuery-like) to find the specific element you want and grab its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that? It looks like you are trying to retrieve the contributions of the user, and that you want to reverse-engineering the html/svg code for that purpose. If that is the case and you are interested in the data, then you should use the GitHub API: https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: Because I want reach the "data-count" attributes and if I'm not wrong this data is not available on GitHub API. And also want to know how can i parse/use dom data with Node.js.